# No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content error

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, audio-recording, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am working with audio recording in windows 10 universal app, i found code [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Audio-Recorder-In-Windows-2d80c2fd/view/Discussions) when i run that code it showing "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content" error, in phone any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> when i run that code it showing "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content" error

If you refer to [MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.createmp3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you will see the following paragraph.

> **Note**  While it is technically possible to call CreateMp3, you cannot use this profile to transcode or encode audio into the MP3 format for Windows Phone Store apps. This is because an MP3 encoder is not shipped with Windows Phone. This API is included for completeness and allows you to use it with 3rd party MP3 encoders that you include with your app.

So if you want this app to work with windows phone, you can't use `MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3`. You can use [MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.createm4a.aspx) instead (please modify the codes in the demo like below):

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MediaCapture capture;
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream buffer;
    bool record;
    string filename;
    string audioFile = "audio.mp4";//originally was audioFIle=".mp3"
    ...
    private async void recordBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (record)
        {
            //already recored process
        }
        else
        {
            await RecordProcess();
            //await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto), buffer);//comment this line out
            await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto), buffer);//added this line
            if (record)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            record = true;
        }

    }
```

Here is the complete modified sample: [AudioRecorderSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/AudioRecorderSample).

Comment: Fixed my problem with audio capture on HoloLens, thanks!