# NAudio throws No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content on production server

Tags: c#, naudio

i have a console app testing NAudio library, the code below works fine on my local machine and on the testing server but throws an error on the production server

the audio file is a .m4a file

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string audioPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudioFile"];
       Console.WriteLine(new AudioFileReader(audioPath).TotalTime.TotalMilliseconds);
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Error Message

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No suitable tr
ansform was found to encode or decode the content. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0
0D5212)
   at NAudio.MediaFoundation.IMFSourceReader.SetCurrentMediaType(Int32 dwStreamI
ndex, IntPtr pdwReserved, IMFMediaType pMediaType)
   at NAudio.Wave.MediaFoundationReader.CreateReader(MediaFoundationReaderSettin
gs settings)
   at NAudio.Wave.MediaFoundationReader.Init(MediaFoundationReaderSettings initi
alSettings)
   at NAudio.Wave.MediaFoundationReader..ctor(String file)
   at NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader.CreateReaderStream(String fileName)
   at NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader..ctor(String fileName)
   at NAudioTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\staff\source\repos\NAud
ioTest\NAudioTest\Program.cs:line 15
```

any suggestions on what could be causing this error ?

Comment: first guess... is the `AudioFile` config setting on the prod server set correctly?

Comment: yes it is, i forgot to mention its a .m4a file, i edited the post to include this

Comment: Try googling the first of the error message: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content.` -- I don't know much about handling audio files so I can't tap into my own personal knowledge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013269/no-suitable-transform-was-found-to-encode-or-decode-the-content-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server you are running on is missing the Media Foundation Codecs that are needed to perform the. You'll have to install the feature (from memory, I think it's the "[Desktop Experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/getting-started-with-server-with-desktop-experience)")